# DHCP Requests cannot get through Switch

Tags: dhcp, switch

First a little about the network setup: We are a smaller department of a larger school. We have 7 offices with TP-Link managed switches as well as 20 APs and 24 classrooms. The switches, APs and classrooms all lead back to the larger school's switch which I am told is an H3C and from there to a router and the internet.

All of our devices are one 1 VLAN and 1 subnet while other departments/programs are on different VLANs.

We are attempting to configure a DHCP server on a Windows Server 2012 R2 but most clients are ending up with APIPA addresses. The few clients that are getting Valid IP configurations are in the same room (and therefore same TP-Link Switch) as the Server.

From what I am reading, my best guess is that the H3C switch is not letting either the requests or the DHCP's response through. Am I right that DHCP relay and or UDP relay not what I need? My understanding it that would be between VLANs or across the router. I am really out of my element with this.

Does anyone have any thoughts why this would happen this way?

Comment: Kt looks like there are [plenty of others](http://forum.tp-link.com/showthread.php?77558-DHCP-Not-Passed-through) with the same issue.  If there's a firmware update available for your switches, I'd give those a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did a check for our firmware but we are running the most recent. By the way, our switches are TL-SL2428WEB. I still think the issue is with the H3C Switch since the computers connected to the same TP-Link switch as the DHCP Server can get IPs without a problem.

Comment: Basically the TP-Link produces low-end equipment. Under normal circumstances, it should be supplied directly on the junkyard, without passing through the retail. But for some reason it's selling widely, multiplying the number of corrupted network installations.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you must have access to the H3C switch if you don't then you are at the mercy of whoever is in charge of your network. Otherwise, you must make sure that there is no other DHCP server running on that specific vlan. Further, yes you are right the H3C switch is probably configured to not let outside DHCP requests through since there is probably already a DHCP server in place for that vlan. Without more info I can't be sure but you may want to get with the Network Specialist/Admin that is in charge of the school and ask him.